# decrypt gpg file with specific key ?? (OS = WindowsXp)

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, gpg, pgp

please how i can decrypt file with specific key in batch file mode ?

for example i want to :-

decrypt file `X.txt` with key `X.pub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using --import and make it default key